# Prove or disprove: if f(x) is continuous at $1$, and $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac {f(x)}{x-1}=1$, then $f(1)=0$.

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm having a little trouble of where to start in this question. 
Intuitively, this seems true, just based on the limit $\frac {sinx}{x}$ when $x\to 0$, but intuition isn't enough, and I'm not getting how to start proving this statement (if it's true anyway). 
 I appreciate any help or hints, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use properties of limits. What happens if you multiply by $\lim_{x\to1}x-1$?

Comment: Hint: Use what's given to you to show that $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = 0$ and then use the definition of contintuity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{f(x)}{x-1}=1$,$$\lim_{x\to1}f(x)=\lim_{x\to1}(x-1)\frac{f(x)}{x-1}=0\times1=0.$$But, since $f$ is continuous at $1$, $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)=f(1)$. Therefore, $f(1)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** $\lim_{x\to1} f(x)/(x-1) = 1$ implies that $f(x)$ near $1$ should be of the form $f(x) = (x-1)^\alpha g(x)$ where $g$ is continuous at $x = 1$ (since $f$ is continuous at $x = 1$).

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=L$ and $\lim_{x\to a}h(x)=M$, you have
$$
\lim_{x\to a}g(x)h(x)=LM.
$$

For your problem, pick $g(x)=x-1$ and $h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x-1}$, $a=1$. Then use the continuity of $f$ at $x=1$.